# Using Javascript variable values in Apex

Tags: visualforce, javascript, map, javascript-remoting

I am trying to show territory details and  calculate few variables in same page on click of territory in Map.

For that, I need to use values which are stored in javascript variable to pass into Apex method.

Any ideas will be appreciated

Please help me.

Comment: You've tagged it with javascript remoting, which sounds indeed the way to go. Have you already tried that ? If you need a start of point:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

Comment: I know that we can access apex method in visualforce through javascript remoting. but can we do vice-versa..???

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean by that. Maybe you can update your question with a more detailed process explanation of what you're trying to achieve.  JS remoting isn't the only option.

Answer (score 2):

Vice-Versa.  You mean directly access JavaScript variables from within the body of Apex methods in your Controller without passing them in somehow?  That's not possible.

However, *Passing* them into an Apex method as parameters is possible with [JavaScript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm). Example [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm).  If you have many, you can always create an Apex class and fill an instance of it in your JavaScript with all of the values you want and pass it. See [this question and answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/visualforce-remoting-passing-wrapper-class-object-as-a-parameter).

Comment: Also, actionFunction tags can access view state, which is sometimes more appropriate. JavaScript remoting doesn't give you view state access.

Answer (score 0):

For This , You can use hidden field -with getter setter values, where ever you are assigning the values to variable ,set hidden field values to variable js...call action function.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [this post](http://th3silverlining.com/2009/09/14/passing-javascript-values-to-apex-code/), and also the comments - see Dave Carroll's link to an alternative method